# Flutter and Firebase authentication via Facebook: Lost connection to device

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to setup Flutter-Firebase-Facebook social authentication as defined [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social/#facebook). I used just the example given in the docs and after I execute `flutter run` and click the 'Login' button on the simulator, the app exits and what I can see from the logged message is just:

> [   +4 ms] Lost connection to device.

Step I followed are the following:

- I setup the Facebook App as described in [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth#installation);
- I also setup the Flutter project for iOS and Android as defined in [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth#installation);
- I ran the exact example described in the flutter_facebook_auth [page](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth#installation);

What I've checked so far is:

- Memory is enough;
- *flutter doctor* does not show any issue.

Version of deps I am using are:

- firebase_core: ^0.7.0
- firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
- flutter_facebook_auth: ^2.0.1

Version of flutter, sdk etc are all latest. Running on Big Sur 11.1

Does anyone know what I can investigate further?

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue, make sure your `CFBundleURLSchemes` starts with **fb**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
  <!--
  Replace "000000000000" with your Facebook App ID here.
  **NOTE**: The scheme needs to start with `fb` and then your ID.
  -->
  <string>fb000000000000</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
  </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and went back through the installation guide to make sure I got everything. What fixed it for me was making sure I had these two properties set in the `Info.plist`:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{your-fb-app-id}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{your-app-name}</string>
```